# Dependent drop down from referencies

Tags: 7, forms

I need to create dependent dropdown lists (like hierarchical select) from several referenced entity types (term_reference, node_reference, user_reference).

To be more clear:

```
- BMW
- - X1
- - - E84
- - X3
- - - E83
- - - F25
- - X5
- - - And so on...
```

- 1 level - taxonomy term from vocabulary 1;
- 2 level - taxonomy term from vocabulary 2, referenced to term from vocabulary 1;
- 3 level - node, referenced to vocabulary 2.

As the result I should get node:nid element.

Or another example:

```
- brand 1
- - model 1
- - model 2
- brand 2
- - model 3
- - model 4
- - and so on..
```

- 1 level - is a node;
- 2 level - node referenced to first-level node.

As the result I should get node:nid of second level node.

I guess I should create field widget that can be used in node create form.

Is it any solution without hardcoding using fapi?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue? I'm currently facing the same situation :(

Comment: I've create my own form through FAPI.
And then hide or show some inputs depends on `$form_state['triggering_element']` value